# Set checked state of a nodelist of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a nodelist of checkboxes. How can I set them all to be checked? The following forEach does not work as `the property checked does not exist on type element`

```
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="chkAddProposalProduct_"]');

checkboxes.forEach(c => { c.checked = true});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAddProposalProduct_{{product.productId}}">
```

Comment: This sounds like a TypeScript problem.

Comment: `===` is for comparing. If you want to set the property use `=`.

Comment: Usually people make the opposite mistake, I don't think I've ever seen it like this.

Comment: @Barmar that was a typo, sorry. I still don't have a `checked` property of 'c'

Comment: Are you sure you're selecting the checkboxes, not the DIV that contains them? Add the HTML to your question.

Comment: Try debugging with `console.log(c)`.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I can debug `checkboxes` in the console and access the checked property of any of the checkboxes using `checkboxes[0]` etc. Is there any issue with my `forEach`?

Comment: @Barmar HTML added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript has no way to know that `checkboxes` contains only `<input type="checkbox">` elements. You could have any element with an ID starting with `chkAddProposalProduct_`. So you need to tell the TypeScript compiler that `checkboxes` is an `NodeList` of `HTMLInputElement` objects, like so:

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="chkAddProposalProduct_"]') as NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>;

checkboxes.forEach(c => { c.checked = true; });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is there a better way I should be going about checking all checkboxes that start with an ID in TypeScript?

Comment: You can change the selector to `input[type=checkbox][id^="chkAddProposalProduct_"]` if you want to be extra sure that only checkboxes are selected.